# Avoid shared lock when using Office365-REST-Python-Client-2.3.16

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365-rest-client

I am trying to update a file on sharepoint using Office365-REST-Python-Client-2.3.16. But if I open this file in a browser, I will always get:

office365.runtime.client_request_exception.ClientRequestException: ('-2147018894, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileLockException', 'The file https://aaa.sharepoint.com/sites/bbb/Shared Documents/ccc.xlsx is locked for shared use by ddd@eee.com [membership].', "423 Client Error: Locked for url: [https://aaa.sharepoint.com/sites/bbb/_api/Web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents')/Files/add(overwrite=true,url='ccc.xlsx')"](https://aaa.sharepoint.com/sites/bbb/_api/Web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%27Shared%20Documents%27)/Files/add(overwrite=true,url=%27ccc.xlsx%27)%22))

The 'bypass-shared-lock' works when I try to delete a file, but doesn't work for uploading a file.

```
def custom_header(request):
    request.headers['Prefer'] = 'bypass-shared-lock'

ctx.before_execute(custom_header)
ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(dir).upload_file(name, content).execute_query()
```

Is it possible to ignore the lock and force update?

Answer (score 0):

The same issue exists with the requests library. For now this looks an issue within Microsoft Graph.

In the Graph portal using bypass-shared-lock in the Request headers, it's only able to delete but NOT update anything. Looking online there doesn't seem to be a workaround yet.

Comment: Which requests library? Is it really literally the same error message?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, same Error 423. Both using the requests library (https://pypi.org/project/requests/) and even Graph Explorer itself. Graph is not allowing us to do this- maybe by design or because it's a bug.